# Detect if CTRL key is pressed when Left Click on DataGridView Header

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have created a class in VB.Net that is a child of `DataGridView`.  I am trying to create a method that detects when there has been a left click on one of the column headers, and then checks to see if the CTRL key is pressed when the click event fires.  This is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub Self_ColumnHeaderLeftClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles Me.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
    If e.Button <> MouseButtons.Left Then Return
    If (Control.ModifierKeys = (Keys.LControlKey Or Keys.RControlKey) Then
        MessageBox.Show(Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name)
    EndIf
End Sub
```

It's suppose to be simple right now, and just pop up a message box when holding either CTRL key and left clicking on one of the headers.  However nothing is happened.  I know the event method is firing, because if I move the `MessageBox` line into an `Else` block under the `If` statement, I get the message boxes appearing.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Control.ModifierKeys` is of type `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` which is an enumerate type annotated with the `FlagsAttribute`.  You probably want to test a condition something like:

```
(Control.ModifierKeys AND Keys.LControlKey = Keys.LControlKey) OR (Control.ModifierKeys AND Keys.RControlKey = Keys.RControlKey)
```

The first half of that expression says "are all the bits of `Keys.LControlKey` set in `Control.ModifierKeys`.  The second half does the same thing for `Keys.RControlKey`.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably adapt this to your needs

```
Private Sub SomeDGV_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object,
                                              e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dgvPending.ColumnHeaderMouseClick

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then

        If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown Then
            'control key down
        Else
            '
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be

```
Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.LControlKey Or Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.RControlKey
```

because `Keys.LControlKey Or Keys.RControlKey` combines the two `Keys` values to form a new one containing both, `LControlKey` and `RControlKey`. This would mean that you have to press both control keys at the same time.

See: [Use Enumerated Values with Bit Flags to Handle Multiple Options](http://www1.visualstudiomagazine.com/Blogs/Tool-Tracker/2013/05/Enumerated-Values-with-Bit-Flags.aspx)

---

Okay, it looks like you are getting a `Keys.Control`, no matter which control key you are pressing. So simply test

```
if Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Control Then
```

Comment: I made the change you suggested, however it is still not working :\